# Tableau - create heatmap with size showing percentage of column and color showing percentage of row

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set with 5 clusters and 10 products.  I have aggregated sales in each of these 50 buckets.  I then fed this into tableau and create a heatmap (clusters = columns, products = rows).

The issue is that some of the clusters are much larger than the others with skews their influence on the overall heatmap.  What I'd like to do is use color to show % of column and size to show rank within the row.  Is there any easy way to do this? Maybe 2 calculated fields?

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Normalize" the data in the table to have them on the same "size", you could do this by dividing each data by the Max-data value. The function WINDOW_MAX(expression, [start, end]) gets the MAX-data value of all the "WINDOW".

Color_to_show = SUM(Cluster_size) / WINDOW_MAX(SUM(Cluster_size))

this will give you a 0-1 value range of color to show heat_map.